# Showing subset is dense

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be finite discrete metric space. Since it is finite and discrete every map from $X$ to real numbers will be bounded and continous. Let $C$ be the set of such functions. I want to show that $C$ is seperable where $C$ is metric space with respect to the norm $||f|| = \sup{f}$.

I consider the set $B =\{f :  \text{the image of $f$ is the subset of rational numbers}\}$

I feel that $C$ has same cardinality as $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $B$ has same cardinality as $\mathbb{Q^n}$ where $n$ is cardinality of $X$. Since $\mathbb{Q^n}$ is seperable in $\mathbb{R^n}$, is it enough to prove that these sets have same cardinal numbers as mentioned above and conclude that $B$ is seperable in $C$?

Or

How can I show that any function which is not in $B$ is limit point of $B$?

Comment: All you have to do is approximate the image of each point by a rational number to get  a function in $B$ approximating the given function.

Comment: Thanks for that!. If $X$ and $Y$ has same cardinality and given that $X$ is seperable then can we conclude that $Y$ is seperable?

Answer (score 1):

In fact $C$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. If $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, let

$$\varphi:C\to\Bbb R^n:f\mapsto\langle f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)\rangle\,;$$

then $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism, and since $\Bbb Q^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R^n$, $\varphi^{-1}\left[\Bbb Q^n\right]$ is a countable dense subset of $C$. The metric induced by the norm on $C$ even translates nicely to $\Bbb R^n$: if

$$B(f,\epsilon)=\{g\in C:\|g-f\|<\epsilon\}$$

is the open $\epsilon$-ball centred at $f$ in $C$, then

$$\varphi[B(f,\epsilon)]=\prod_{k=1}^n\big(f(x_k)-\epsilon,f(x_k)+\epsilon\big)\,,$$

the open box of side length $2\epsilon$ centred at $\varphi(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment : Consider $X$ to be the Sorgenfrey plane and $Y$ to be its anti-diagonal. Then, even though $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality and $X$ is separable, the same does not hold for $Y$.

Regarding your question : I read $B=\lbrace f\in C : f(X)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\rbrace$. Let $f\in C$ and $\epsilon >0$. Pick $q_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|f(x_i)-q_i|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for every $x_i\in X=\lbrace x_1,... x_n\rbrace$. Then, $g\in B$ such that $g(x_i)=q_i$ is such that $||g-f||<\epsilon$